# Xamarin Forms accessibility features font size

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

If I have a label, how do I get it to adjust to larger font sizes as expressed by a user's accessibility settings?  I have scoured the Internet and can't find any articles related to this issue.

```
 <Label FontSize="14" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [Named Font Sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#named-font-sizes)

- Body
- Caption
- Default
- Header
- Large
- Medium
- Micro
- Small
- Subtitle
- Title

> On iOS and Android, named font sizes will autoscale based on operating
>   system accessibility options.